# Ending a thread properly in QT

Tags: qt

How do I ensure that my thread is deleted in QT after I run it. I have tried to connect the finished signal with a delete slot I created but it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Destructor Connections
connect(this, SIGNAL(finished()), &cThread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(this, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(&cThread, SIGNAL(finished()), &cThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

This should work for C++

Comment: Make sure that you specify this in the constructor of your thread.